# How to get data in a form event within a CollectionType?

Tags: mongodb, forms, symfony, event-listener

I have a problem with Symfony 4 on an issue already identified and described on Github (here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5694#issuecomment-110398953) but I can't find a way to apply this answer.

When I try to use a POST_SET_DATA form event in a ChildType form, the function getData() gives me a null value because the "allow_add" option is set on true in the ParentType form which is a CollectionType.

I have 3 collections: Page, Moduling and Module. The Moduling document is used to embed a collection of Module forms. The purpose is to be able to add multiple forms to the Page collection with one request, following this Symfony article: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html.

I have 2 different embedded documents: Tag and Task. Both of them are embedded in the Module document (EmbedOne). What I want to do is to be able to custom the ModuleType field with a form event listener so that I just need to set the title of the Module in the controller and then Symfony knows it needs to use the TaskType or the TagType within the ModuleType.

So first, here is my controller

```
class TaskingController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * The controller from which I set the module title, "task" here
     *
     * @Route("/{slug}/task/create", name="tasking_create")
     * 
     * @ParamConverter("page", options={"mapping": {"slug": "slug"}})
     * 
     * @return Response
     */
    public function createTasking(DocumentManager $dm, $id, Module $module, Moduling $moduling)
    {
        $page = $dm->find(Page::class, $id);

        $module->setTitle('task');

        $moduling->addModule($module);
        $page->addModuling($moduling);

        $form = $this->createForm(ModulingType, $moduling);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid() && $form->isSubmitted() {
            // Form validation then redirection
        }
        // Render form template}
    }
}
```

Now, here are my three collections: pages, moduling and modules

```
/**  
 * My page document
 *
 * @MongoDB\Document(collection="pages")
 */
class Page
{
    /** 
     * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="App\Document\Moduling")
     * 
     * @var Moduling
     */
    protected $moduling = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->moduling = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of id
     */ 
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection $moduling
     */    
    public function getModuling()
    {
        return $this->moduling;
    }

    /**
     * @param Moduling $moduling
     */
    public function addModuling(Moduling $moduling)
    {
        $this->moduling[] = $moduling;
    }

    /**
     * @param Moduling $moduling
     */
    public function removeModuling(Moduling $moduling)
    {
        $this->moduling->removeElement($moduling);
    }
}

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(collection="moduling")
 */
class Moduling
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="App\Document\Page", storeAs="id")
     * 
     * @var Page
     */
    protected $parentPage;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="App\Document\Module", mappedBy="moduling")
     */
    protected $module = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->module = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getModule()
    {
        return $this->module;
    }

    public function addModule(Module $module): self
    {   
        $this->module[] = $module;
    }

    public function removeModule(Module $module)
    {
        $this->module->removeElement($module);
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of parentPage
     *
     * @return  Page
     */ 
    public function getParentPage()
    {
        return $this->parentPage;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of parentPage
     *
     * @param  Page  $parentPage
     *
     * @return  self
     */ 
    public function setParentPage(Page $parentPage)
    {
        $this->parentPage = $parentPage;

        return $this;
    }
}

/**  
 * @MongoDB\Document(collection="modules")
 */
class Module
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     */
    public $title;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="App\Document\Moduling", inversedBy="module", storeAs="id")
     */
    public $moduling;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\EmbedOne(targetDocument="App\Document\Task", strategy="set")
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    public $task;

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * @return  self
     */ 
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTask()
    {
        return $this->task;
    }

    public function setTask(Task $task = null)
    {
        $this->task = $task;
    }
}
```

My embedded document Task. The Tag document has the same structure.

```
/**  
 * @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument
 */
class Task
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

My ModulingType, which is a collection of ModuleType

```
class ModulingType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('module', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => ModuleType::class,
                'entry_options' => [
                    'label' => false,
                ],
                'by_reference' => false,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true
                ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Moduling::class
        ]);
    }
}

class ModuleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $module = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();

            if ('task' == $module->getTitle()) {
                $form->add('task', TaskType::class);
            }
        });
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Module::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

So I have identified the problem. When I try to make this work, Symfony sends me this error message: "Call to a member function getTitle() on null". It seems the getData() doesn't get anything.

Actually, after reading few posts on Github I've realized that the "allow_add" option set on "true" was the origin of this issue. And indeed, when I set it on "false" I don't have any error message. But the consequence of this is that my JQuery doesn't allow me to duplicate the form if I want to, the "allow_add" option is necessary to do that.

In the Github post I uploaded, they say that the solution is to write this code first in the ModuleType:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
    if (null != $event->getData()) {
    }
}
```

It's what I did but it doesn't change anything. I wrote this, followed by the code written in the ModuleType but I still have the same error message... Perhaps I don't know how to insert it correctly in the ModuleType.

I hope someone has a solution. I know I can still add the Tag and Task types directly in the ModulingType but I would have more collections.

Thanks a lot for helping me, I hope I've been clear enough!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this:

```
if (!is_null($module) && 'task' == $module->getTitle()) {
    $form->add('task', TaskType::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So actually I found a solution, I was really closed, but I got a new problem...

```
class ModuleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $module = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();

            if (null != $event->getData()) {
                if ('task' == $module->getTitle()) {
                    $form->add('task', TaskType::class);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Module::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

This was the solution so as you can see it was not that complicated BUT the fact of using a form event in the ModuleType creates a new issue.

In my ModulingType, I add an option

```
'allow_add' => true,
```

This really useful tool allows to automatically add a "data-prototype" in my form so that I can copy/past some jQuery lines available here (https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) and then be able to duplicate or delete my form. However, when using a form event, the data-prototype doesn't register anything as it is created before my TaskType.

So after spending hours reading discussions on Github and trying to find the solution, I came to the conclusion I had to create a TaskingType and a TagingType, which look like this:

```
class TaskingType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('task', TaskType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Module::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

So ok, this solution is not perfect and I have some code duplication. But at least it allows me to only have 3 collections: Page, Moduling and Module.

If someone finds an elegant way to manage everything with one form without deleting the content available in data-prototype, please keep me posted :)